# find and use a 'rel' link with simple_html_dom

Tags: php, html, parsing

I am using php_simple_html_dom to parse a web site.
All is well until I try to access a popup dialog which contains a table with data that I need.
On main page is the following:

```
 <div class="className" rel="/url-of-popup.htm?section=212">Link</div>
```

This is a button which links to new page as a popup.
Using the web inspector, I have tried to drill down through all elements but I cannot get to that table.
If I hard code the url into my $html variable, there is no problem.
However that section number (212) is different for each new page.

What I need help with is how to have the parser find that "rel" link and save it in a variable so I can then access the table data.

I hope that all makes sense.
Thanks

Comment: can you even use `url-of-popup.html?section=212`  ? if im not mistaken or i might not know, it should be `.php` rather than a `.html` . correct me if im wrong here.

Comment: This is the format taken from the the web site. It isn't the actual link but it is the same markup.

Comment: did you try `foreach($html->find('div') as $element){echo $element->rel;}`, what do it returns?

Comment: there are 8 such divs on the page and this returns all 8. excelent!! Now I just need to access the one I need. Thanks a lot.